# Ruby Contact Mailer not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple script for my contact_mailer.rb  which has a simple form as the front end with one dropdown to select purpose and has a switch-case block to choose the email ID accordingly. Now, somehow mail is always being sent to the first one i.e. when 'localization'.

Only this gets fired whatever be selected. Please explain why this may be happening. Am pasting code snippet below for reference:

```
class ContactUsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "bot@mydomain.com"

  def contact_us_email(name, message, purpose, email)
    @name = name
    @message = message
    @purpose = purpose
    @email = email
    content_type "text/html"

    case @purpose
    when 'localization'
        mail(:to => 'me@mydomain.com', :subject => purpose)
    when 'marketing'
        mail(:to => 'me@mydomain.com', :cc => 'me@mydomain.com, me@mydomain.com', :subject => purpose)
    when 'network'
        mail(:to => 'me.agm@gmail.com', :subject => purpose)
    when 'recruitment'
        mail(:to => 'me@mydomain.com', :cc => 'me@mydomain.com', :subject => purpose)
    when 'general'
        mail(:to => 'me@mydomain.com', :subject => purpose)
    else
        mail(:to => 'me@mydomain.com', :subject => purpose)
    end

  end
end
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Have you made sure that `purpose` has the correct value each time this method gets called?

Comment: Actually, I have been told to fix this issue. But, I have background in php. I think it gets the right value, I have verified the front-end. But, on the production server, if I make any changes to .rb they are not getting reflected. Can you please suggest why this is happening and how to fix this ?
I reloaded apache and tried restarting as well...

Comment: I see. Do you call the mailer from a controller? What does that controller action look like?

Comment: This is the controller call:`code` # sends contact us email
 def contact_us
  langSlug = getSessionLanguageOrDefault()

  name = params[:name]
  message = params[:message]
  purpose = params[:purpose]
  email = params[:email]
  ContactUsMailer.contact_us_email(name, message, purpose, email).deliver
  render :partial => "application/contact_thank_you-" + langSlug + partial_extension
 end`code`